# Clicking noise in rear wheel that stops on load. Bearings?

Tags: wheels, bearings

The bike is a Merida Speeder 10 flatbar and about a month old.

I've noticed a rhythmic clicking from the rear wheel. At first I thought the wheel may be bent and the break pads were catching, but that is fine. I also noticed that the noise stops when there is load, eg: when I am pedaling up a hill.

The noise occurs both when cruising and when free wheeling. It happens in any gear and at any speed.

Could the bearing be worn?

Comment: If it only happens when you're **not** pedaling it's probably the "freehub" pawls in the rear hub.  Normal.

Comment: Does the clicking get faster if you pedal backward while coasting forward?

Comment: Since its only a month old, its under warranty.  Go back to the source and have them solve it.  Should be no charge for the work too, at least in most western countries.   Are you positive its not the freewheel operating like normal?  Some brands click seriously loudly.

Comment: Daniel Hicks: freehub pawls? Can you explain what that means? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this was the bearing. The wheel was cheap, as was the bearing, and was slightly buckled. The bearing just got worn out.

I would not recommend this bike (Merida Speeder 10) as the quality is terrible.

Comment: It’s a 500 AUD or around 400 USD bicycle. Not a BSO but “entry-level.” They get to this price level by having everything machine assembled and minimal quality control. The one saving grace is the ability to actually (in most cases) have some warranty support and you should take advantage of this by making sure every last thing is fixed while it’s under warranty.

Comment: Thank you for coming back and providing closure on this question - its much appreciated.

Comment: @RoboKaren Yes, to their credit the store I bought it from (not Merida) replaced both the wheel and gears with upgraded versions for free. Hopefully they got refunded somehow from the company. I knew it was a cheap bike, but man I didn't think I would have this sort of problem after only a month.

Answer (score -1):

There are many issues possible. It could be the rear gears need tuning or the axles could be bent. It could also be that the wheel is simply out of balance. I would recommend taking the bike to a shop to at least diagnose it as the problem could be from a variety of factors.

However, if the problem isn't really affecting your ride, i would just leave it as most times you end up wasting money fixing trivial problems.

But thats just my opinion. Good Luck!

Comment: The bike's only a month old -- it shouldn't be making any noises and any fixes should be covered by the warranty.

Comment: Also "that's just my opinion" types of answers are generally frowned upon.

Comment: I didn't want to misrepresent my opinion as the definite answer. I will take it into account and not write "thats just my opinion." Thank you, JohnP.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Your answer essentially boils down to "take it to a shop." A better answer would include some diagnostic tips for the OP and perhaps some quick easy fixes. Please consider expanding your answer to offer the OP more solutions than a recommendation to take it to shop. A short  answer like this is likely to get downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.